# Unable to generate Production Build to Publish on App store

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to generate the Production build using Appcelrator Studio but I am getting following error.

```
[ERROR] :  ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
[ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
[ERROR] :   CompileAssetCatalog Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/XYZ/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/XYZ.app Assets.xcassets
[ERROR] :  (1 failure)
```

Below is the Settings and Configuration.
Appcelerator Version: **5.1.0.201808080937**
Appcelerator SDK: **7.2.0.GA**
Mac OS Version: **10.13.3**
Node.js Version: **8.9.1**
npm Version: **5.5.1**
CLI Version: **5.1.1**
Xcode Version: **9.4.1**

The Provisioning Profile and the Production Certificate is the same which I was using previously.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you have a problem with your assets (graphics)

Comment: But I have not added or removed any graphic content (image) in my project.

Comment: even application icon?

Comment: even the application icon is untouched. What could be the reason?

Comment: strange, my advice would be to create a fresh project and copy resources from it to your current project.

Comment: I will try that and let you know.

Comment: Delete your build folder and then compile again

Comment: Deleting the build folder worked. Thanks Vanitha. :)

Comment: @Vanitha please write this as an answer so it can be marked as the correct answer to this post in case people find it